# How to initialize rows of 2D array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, char

I want to store strings in a 2D array using pointers but I'm confused with how to do it. The examples I've seen use only arrays of ints or use the brackets[] to allocate a fixed size of memory. So I'm trying to initialize my 2D array of strings and this is what I have:

```
char ** stringArr = (char**)malloc(/*I don't know what goes here*/);
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    stringArr[i] = (char*)malloc(cols *sizeof(char));
```

As you can see the parameter for my first call of malloc, I am stuck as to what to put there if I want an exact x number of rows, where each row stores a string of chars. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this, because you're allocating some number of pointers:

```
malloc(rows * sizeof(char*))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the number of rows.

```
char ** stringArr = malloc(rows * sizeof(char*));
```

Also, do not typecast the return value of a malloc() call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but why shouldn't I typecast malloc()? Even cplusplus.com typecasts it in its reference page on malloc().

Comment: @Ghost_Stark Here is a protected link on the subject! Hope it makes things clearer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 0):

Use `sizeof *ptr * N`.

Notice how this method uses the correct type even if `stringArr` was `char ** stringArr` or `int ** stringArr`.

```
stringArr = malloc(sizeof *stringArr * rows);
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    stringArr[i] = malloc(sizeof *(stringArr[i]) * cols);
```